# Is this Haskell code equivalent to this Python code?

Tags: python, haskell, numpy

I'm trying to port a Python program to Haskell, and I'm fairly new to NumPy (which the Python program uses) So I'm wondering why this code isn't equivalent.
Here's my Haskell code:

```
data NNetwork = NNetwork { nlayers :: Int
                         , sizes   :: [Int]
                         , biases  :: [[Float]]
                         , weights :: [[Float]] }
                deriving (Show, Ord, Eq)

buildNetwork :: [Int] -> NNetwork
buildNetwork sizes = NNetwork { nlayers = length sizes
                              , sizes   = sizes
                              , biases  = map (\y -> replicate y (sig . toFloat . rands $ y)) sizes
                              , weights = map (\y -> replicate y (toFloat $ rands y)) sizes }
feedforward :: NNetwork -> Float -> [[Float]]
feedforward net a = map (equation a) (zip (weights net) (biases net))

toFloat x = fromIntegral x :: Float

sig :: Float -> Float
sig a = 1 / (1 + exp (-a))

rands :: Int -> Int
rands x = (7 * x) `mod` 11

equation :: Float -> ([Float], [Float]) -> [Float]
equation a (w, b) = map sig $ zipWith (+) (dot w (rep w a)) b
  where dot = zipWith (*)
        rep a b = replicate (length a) b
```

And the original Python code:

```
class Network(object):

    def __init__(self, sizes):
        self.num_layers = len(sizes)
        self.sizes = sizes
        self.biases = [np.random.randn(y, 1) for y in sizes[1:]]
        self.weights = [np.random.randn(y, x) 
                        for x, y in zip(sizes[:-1], sizes[1:])]

def sigmoid(z):
    return 1.0/(1.0+np.exp(-z))

def feedforward(self, a):
        """Return the output of the network if "a" is input."""
        for b, w in zip(self.biases, self.weights):
            a = sigmoid(np.dot(w, a)+b)
        return a
```

I'm trying to port a very simple neural network program from Python to Haskell, because I enjoy Haskell much more. I'm also worried that I'm doing something wrong, because the Haskell code is far more verbose.

- Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that in `feedforward` `a` should have type `Float`? Shouldn't the input to the network be a vector like `[Float]`, or does the network always have only one input? If the network has more than one input, each neuron should have a vector of weights `[Float]`, a layer would be multiple neurons `[[Float]]` and the entire multiple layer network would be multiple layers `[[[Float]]]`.

Comment: Yeah, I just came to that (or a similar) conciliation just now. I'm really messing with stuff I don't understand very well here, though. Thanks!

Comment: You could write unit tests for both programs and compare the results.

Comment: You might interested in this simple [Python implementation](http://iamtrask.github.io/2015/07/12/basic-python-network/) and this [Haskell version](https://gist.github.com/gatlin/e81b8c572b2f284f1423)

Comment: Well, there is an obvious difference. `np.random.randn` isn't a pure function while your `rands` is. If you want to generate random numbers in Haskell you'd have to use [`System.Random`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.1/docs/System-Random.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: note that the Python version lacks the equivalent of `deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)` — try implementing the corresponding `__magic__` methods and see how many lines of code are added. Without these, `==`, `<=`, `>`, as well as `print Network()` make little to no sense.

Basically the verbosity mainly comes from the type signatures. Also, you can move `rands` to a `where` block under `buildNetwork` and simply completely get rid of `toFloat` by replacing any calls to `toFloat` with `fromIntegral` with no type annotation. Plus perhaps some other tiny refactorings.

In general, you can expect, in some situations, for some things to be somewhat more verbose in languages that are generally much more concise. I'm sure as your neural network program progresses towards a more substantial code base, Haskell will be less verbose than Python, ignoring the possible existence of neural network libraries for Python that might be more mature than their (possibly non-existent) Haskell counterparts.

```hs
data NNetwork = NNetwork { nlayers :: Int
                         , sizes   :: [Int]
                         , biases  :: [[Float]]
                         , weights :: [[Float]] }
                deriving (Show, Ord, Eq)

buildNetwork sizes =
  NNetwork { nlayers = length sizes
           , sizes   = sizes
           , biases  = map (\y -> replicate y (sig . fromIntegral . rands $ y)) sizes
           , weights = map (\y -> replicate y (fromIntegral . rands $ y)) sizes }
  where rands x = (7 * x) `mod` 11

feedforward net a = map (equation a) (zip (weights net) (biases net))

sig a = 1 / (1 + exp (-a))

equation a (w, b) = map sig $ zipWith (+) (dot w rep) b
  where dot = zipWith (*)
        rep = replicate (length w) a
```

and well you can do some micro-refactorings in the `buildNetwork` to remove some minor duplication but that would just shorten the lines, and would possibly make the code less readable to a domain expert:

```hs
buildNetwork sizes =
  NNetwork { nlayers = length sizes
           , sizes   = sizes
           , biases  = nameMe sig
           , weights = nameMe id }
  where nameMe fn = map (replicate y (fn y')) sizes
        y'        = fromIntegral $ y * 7 `mod` 11
```